# python multi-threading lock is not working as expected when doing number change

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-multithreading

I am learning python3 multi-threading now and trying to test the following code. what the code does is to use multiple thread to modify a global number `balance`  (initial value = 0) in a function named `test_change` by first adding and then substracting a same number, and using a thread lock to ensure the `balance` variable will be changed by one thread at a time. And I am looping it for 100000 or more times to check weather the expected value 0 is displayed, however, quite disappointedly, 0 is not always the answer i can get. Here is the code below. And the editor I am using is Vscode.

```py
balance = 0
def test_change(n):
    global balance
    balance += n
    balance -= n
    # print("in {}, balance is {}".format(threading.current_thread().name, balance))


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    """ self-defined threading class """
    def __init__(self, target_fun, fun_args, loop=False):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.target_fun = target_fun
        self.fun_args = fun_args
        self.loop = loop
        self.threadLock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):  # overwrite parent run function
        if not self.loop:
            self.target_fun(*self.fun_args)
        elif self.loop:
            # with self.threadLock:  # balance [15]
                # for i in range(1000000):
                    # self.target_fun(self.fun_args)
            for i in range(100000):
                self.threadLock.acquire()
                self.target_fun(self.fun_args)
                self.threadLock.release()


nums = [5, 12]
thread_list = []
for i in range(2):  # create 2 thread object
    t = MyThread(target_fun=test_change, fun_args=nums[i], loop=True)
    thread_list.append(t)

for i in range(len(thread_list)):  # start thread object
    thread_list[i].start()

for i in range(len(thread_list)):  # stop main thread till subthread finishes 
    thread_list[i].join()  

print("balance [{}]".format(balance))  # expected to be 0 always
print("subthread finishes")
```

and here is part of the execution result that displayed, you can see the last output.

```
(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 &ython.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugface_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 &ython.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugface_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 2863 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 2870 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 3383 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 3389 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 3394 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 3401 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 3406 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [0]
subthread finishes

(face36) D:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506> cd d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506 && cmd /C "C:\LeeSRSPrgoramFile\A_anaconda\envs\face36\python.exe c:\Users\lijin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher 3414 -- d:\P_project_SRS\face_cumstom_dual_cam_0506\threading_producer_consumer.py "
balance [12]  --> this is the result should never happened when using a lock.
subthread finishes
```

I have tried two python grammar for enable a lock which are `with self.threadLock:` (see the commented out part inside the class run function) and `self.threadLock.acquire(), self.threadLock.release()`, is there anyone can help to explain this oddity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread you create is given its *own* instance of a `Lock()`, and they have nothing to do with each other. To provide mutual exclusion, both threads have to use the *same* `Lock` object. For example, create a single instance of a `Lock` at module level, and pass it to the thread's constructor.

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem, here is the code I have done the the correction according to your suggestion, it gives the expected 0 on every execution.
```python
```

Answer (score 0):

by following @Tim Peters suggestion, I have the code modified as follows.

```py
import time
import threading

from threading import Thread

balance = 0
def test_change(n):
    global balance
    balance += n
    balance -= n
    print("in {}, balance is {}".format(threading.current_thread().name, balance))


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    """ self-defined threading class """
    def __init__(self, lock, target_fun, fun_args, loop=False):  # added a shared lock parameter
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.target_fun = target_fun
        self.fun_args = fun_args
        self.loop = loop
        self.lock = lock  # this is the shared lock

    def run(self):  # overwrite parent run function
        if not self.loop:
            self.target_fun(*self.fun_args)
        elif self.loop:
            for i in range(100):
                with self.lock:  # "with" after "for" so that both thread change the "balance" variable alternatively
                    self.target_fun(self.fun_args)

nums = [5, 12]
thread_list = []
thread_muduleLock = threading.Lock()  # added a shared lock

start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(2):
    t = MyThread(thread_muduleLock, target_fun=test_change, fun_args=nums[i], loop=True)  # passing the shared lock to the thread constructor
    thread_list.append(t)

for i in range(len(thread_list)):
    thread_list[i].start()

for i in range(len(thread_list)):
    thread_list[i].join()  
end = time.perf_counter()
total = end - start
print("balance [{}], total time [{}]".format(balance, total))
print("subthread finishes")
```

here is the execution result:

```
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-7, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
in Thread-6, balance is 0
balance [0], total time [0.1192338]
subthread finishes
```

In addition to those above, I have tried to compare the efficiency between `with` and `acquire(), release()` statement, found that the former is a bit faster than the latter, here's the result for 100 loops as below.

```
"""with"""
for i in range(100):  # with after for, 
    with self.lock:
        self.target_fun(self.fun_args)

###### result ######
balance [0], total time [0.0022132000000000002]
subthread finishes

"""acquire & release """
for i in range(100):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.target_fun(self.fun_args)
    self.lock.release()

###### result ######
balance [0], total time [0.0035131000000000003]
subthread finishes
```